# Cordova - refuse to execute inline event handler because it violates the following content Security policy

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, content-security-policy

I'm training for Cordova application development and I turn around a problem with Content Security Policy.

My application is running with the Android emulator, but when I have to execute a javascript I get a message in NetBeans (output window).

```
Refused to execute inline event handler because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' https://ssl.gstatic.com". (22:35:56:126 | error, security)
  at www/index.html:58
```

My code is below. This is my index.html. 
I try to understand how CSP works and I think I understand the concept, but in this case, I don't understand the problem. Line 58 is the comment.

```
<html>        
    <head>   

        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' * data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self'; script-src 'self' https://ssl.gstatic.com; media-src *">
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">

        <title>Hello World</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">

    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="app">
            <h1>Apache Cordova</h1>
            <div id="deviceready" class="blink">
                <p class="event listening">Connecting to Device</p>
                <p class="event received">Device is Ready</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!--
        line 58
        -->
        <button onclick="capturePhoto();">Capture Photo</button> <br>

        <img style="display:none;width:80px;height:80px;" id="smallImage" src="" />
        <img style="display:none;" id="largeImage" src="" />

        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    </body>        
  </html>
```

By advance thanks for your help because I need it. 
Jérôme

Comment: can you relax or remove the CSP?

Comment: if i do that i get 

`Uncaught ReferenceError: capturePhoto is not defined`

and i get 

`No Content-Security-Policy meta tag found. Please add one when using the cordova-plugin-whitelist plugin.`

Comment: Have you tried adding `'unsafe-inline'` to the script-src?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Check this [link](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy), it says:

> Inline JavaScript will not be executed. This restriction bans both inline `<script>` blocks and inline event handlers `(e.g. button onclick="...")`.

To avoid cross-site scripting issues like below specified

```
one.app#/home:1 Refused to execute inline event handler because it violates the following Content
Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'nonce-d452460d-e219-a6e5-5709-c8af6ca82889'
chrome-extension: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' https://sfdc.azureedge.net 
*.na34.visual.force.com https://ssl.gstatic.com/accessibility/". Note that 'unsafe-inline'
is ignored if either a hash or nonce value is present in the source list.
```

Go for `event listener functions` instead of `onclick='myFun()"`.

```
<body onload="main();">
    <button onclick="clickHandler(this)">
        Click for awesomeness!
    </button>
</body>
<script>
    function clickHandler(element) {
        // On click Code
    }

    function main() {
        // Initialization work goes here.
    }
</script>
```

In order to to work with new Browser you need to write your code with a clean separation between content and behavior.

```
<body>
  <button>Click for awesomeness!</button>
</body>
<script src="popup.js"></script>

<!-- popup.js -->
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
      document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', clickHandler);
      main();
    });

    function clickHandler(element) {
        // On click Code
    }

    function main() {
        // Initialization work goes here.
    }
<!-- popup.js -->
```

Comment: Thank you. It's work now. And Thank you for the link, this help is easier to understand.

Comment: adding event listeners for "change", "click" etc. is the best way to go

Answer (score -1):

Try adding `img-src *` to the Content-Security-Policy tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
         content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *; img-src *">
```