# This is the code in my index.html in eclipse. However, when the Click button is clicked, nothing happens. What can be the flaw?

Tags: eclipse, cordova

This is the code in my `index.html` file in Eclipse. The `javascript` part is not working.

When I click the "Click" button, `send()` function is not implemented. alert box does not appear.

Even if I do `<button onClick="alert('heloo')">Click</button>`, no alert appears.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">

        <title>Hello World</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>hello</p>
        <button onClick="send()">Click</button>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function send(){
                alert("Heloo");
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31060722/cordova-refuse-to-execute-inline-event-handler-because-it-violates-the-followi