# Implementing ads into a Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

According to the Google Developer program policy (https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/program_policies) it is perfectly acceptable to add ads into your chrome extension:

> Ads must be presented in context or clearly state which app or extension they are bundled with. Ads must also be easily removable by either adjusting the settings or uninstalling the app or extension altogether. Ads may not simulate or impersonate system notifications or warnings.

Therefore I am trying to add ads, and I'm using Chitika for that, since AdSense is not allowed. It's taken me so long to get close to having ads, I've had to edit minified files and so much more to get compliant with the Chrome extension manifest `content_security_policy`. Anyway, as of right now, only 1 company's ads are showing up, but the rest get blocked with the error message:

`getads.js:340 Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' https://www.google-analytics.com https://secure.adnxs.com https://gum.criteo.com https://ib.adnxs.com https://mm.chitika.net https://cdn.chitika.net". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-KaerrywnDX+trLhtIG9qlTDyP6iiK4PCLN7LWCvctFc='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.`

What can I do to fix this? I've tried adding the keyworkd `unsafe-inline` but I just get another error message of:

`Ignored insecure CSP value "'unsafe-inline'" in directive 'object-src'.`

What can I do at this point? I don't really control how the ads are embedded into my software, so I am somewhat limited. Anyone have an idea? and if not, is there another ad platform that works well with Chrome extensions? I don't want anything annoying.. just a 320x50 ad or something.. and it's getting so frustrating because I get 8 million page impressions on my chrome extension per month and I can't generate any income!

Thanks for the help.

Edit: This is my ad code:

```
( function() {
if (window.CHITIKA === undefined) { window.CHITIKA = { 'units' : [] }; };
var unit = {"calltype":"async[2]","publisher":"USER_NAME","width":300,"height":250,"sid":"Chitika Default"};
var placement_id = window.CHITIKA.units.length;
window.CHITIKA.units.push(unit);
document.write('<div id="chitikaAdBlock-' + placement_id + '"></div>');
}());
```

and you have to include:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/getads.js" async></script>` which can be found here: http://cdn.chitika.net/getads.js. I replaced all the domain name with the `https` version.

Edit 2: My `content_security_policy` looks like this:

```
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://www.google-analytics.com https://secure.adnxs.com https://gum.criteo.com https://ib.adnxs.com https://mm.chitika.net https://cdn.chitika.net; object-src 'self'",
```

Comment: Try embedding the ad into iframe. Maybe add `frame-src 'none'` to CSP. I'm just guessing.

Comment: Can you please show the advertisement code?

Comment: Have you seen Google's [Content Security Policy](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy) and [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31060722/cordova-refuse-to-execute-inline-event-handler-because-it-violates-the-followi)?

Comment: Also, which company is the only one that is showing away?

Comment: @JonathanLam I edited the post. I'm trying to use Chitika as the ad service.

Thank you for trying to help!

Comment: Is your ad code within its own JS file, or is it inside a `<script>` tag in your markup?

Comment: Probably a silly question: Have you tried using the directive `'unsafe-inline'` in the `script-src` section instead of the `object-src` section?

Comment: Let's delete this extension right away. No, let's not even install it.

Answer (score 0):

On the [developer program policies](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/program_policies#ads) website you can find follow remark:

> Currently, AdSense may not be used to serve ads in Chrome Extensions
>   or Chrome Apps, per [AdSense policies](https://support.google.com/adsense/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=48182).

So in fact it means that now you couldn't use ads in your chrome extensions.

Comment: This in an incorrect reading of the CWS policy. The section you quoted signals that you cannot use Google's AdSense program. You're still able to use other services, you just have to find another ad platform that permits displaying ads in bowser extensions.

Answer (score -1):

If unsafe-inline is not working, then try to use a hash to identify each of the scripts you are trying to execute. This way if the code trying to be executed in the html corresponds to the hashes you defined, then the code will be executed. More info about this here: http://www.w3.org/TR/2015/CR-CSP2-20150721/#script-src-hash-usage