# Cannot execute script due to Content Security Policy

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I have a local server running with Node Js. At the end I would like to have a button that refreshes the page but every time I press it it outputs `CANNOT GET /page due to Content Security Policy` and these two errors:

1) Refused to execute a script because its hash, its nonce, or 'unsafe-inline' appears in neither the script-src directive nor the default-src directive of the Content Security Policy.

2) Refused to apply a stylesheet because its hash, its nonce, or 'unsafe-inline' appears in neither the style-src directive nor the default-src directive of the Content Security Policy.

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *; img-src *">
</head>

<body>

  <button id="myBtn">Try it</button>

  <script>

  document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", resetPage);

  function resetPage() {
      location.reload();
  }
 </script>

</body>
```

Does somebody know how to fix this? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cordova - refuse to execute inline event handler because it violates the following content Security policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31060722/cordova-refuse-to-execute-inline-event-handler-because-it-violates-the-followi)

Comment: This is a client side (not a nodejs) error and is related to the rules you set with the `Content-Security-Policy`.

Comment: @t.niese Ok, how do I set them in this case? Thank you!