# PHP/Apache: Refused to load the google "www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js" script due to Content Security Policy

Tags: javascript, php, apache, symfony

I am coding a PHP view that display Google charts, at DocumentRoot of Apache, in a single HTML it works, but when I put the same code inside the PHP page, the browser throws an exception like so:

**It happens at calling the script by src tag:**

```
Refused to load the script 'https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js' 
because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". 
Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.
```

**It happens at in line script, the code is in the page:**

```
Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: 
"default-src 'self'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, 
a hash ('sha256-gCemxHcM8ctzTMqVc2498nRLFHED+rKI4ZaErIVSSk0='), 
or a nonce ('nonce-...') 
is required to enable inline execution. 
Note also that 'script-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.
```

My virtualhost is the following: php743.localhost.com

I have been looking for a solution for both inside the app and on Apache, but I could not fix it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31060722/cordova-refuse-to-execute-inline-event-handler-because-it-violates-the-followi/31065853#31065853) answer your question?

Comment: did you try to add:  Header set Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self';" in your httpd.conf file ? For google fonts I had to add "style-src 'self' fonts.googleapis.com '<myhash>' "

Comment: Alexandre Tranchant. It is a nice approach, but the problem is not just regarding in-line and both in-line and outside js calls such as those found at "https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js" (Google Charts)